# Python overwrite config file with variables stored in other file

Tags: python-2.7, configuration, config, overriding

Suppose I have a file called `main_config.py` and `custom_config.py`. They are both in the same module.

What I want to do is have two separate config files, where one of them (main) is version controlled, and the other one (custom) is `.gitignore`'d to allow different setups have their own configs with the `main` file used as a template.

The code belows used to work properly on Python 3.5, but I was forced to revert to 2.7 and it is no longer working as expected. What am I doing wrong? I'm getting `KeyError: 'client2'` exception on the line with `exec`.

Contents of `main_config.py`:

```
class MainConfig(object):
    clients = {
        "client1" = {
            "IP" = "127.0.0.1",
            "User" = "admin"
        }
    }

    try:
        with(open(__file__.replace("main_config.py", "custom_config.py")) as source_file:
            exec(source_file.read())
    except IOError, e:
        print("No custom config detected")
```

Contents of `custom_config.py`:

```
from (...).main_config import MainConfig

MainConfig.clients["client2"]["IP"] = "0.0.0.0"
MainConfig.clients["client2"]["User"] = "root"
```

Answer (score 1):

I see you use dictionary and `=` sign instead of `:`.

Aside from that, you cannot assign `IP` without `client2` assigned before it so your code could look like this:

`main_config.py`

```
class MainConfig(object):
    clients = {
        "client1" : {
            "IP" : "127.0.0.1",
            "User" : "admin"
        }
    }

    try:
        with(open(__file__.replace("main_config.py", "custom_config.py")) as source_file:
            exec(source_file.read())
    except IOError, e:
        print("No custom config detected")
```

`custom_config.py`

```
    from (...).main_config import MainConfig

if 'client2' not in MainConfig.clients.keys():
    MainConfig.clients["client2"] = {}
MainConfig.clients["client2"]["IP"] = "0.0.0.0"
MainConfig.clients["client2"]["User"] = "root"
```

Comment: Concerning `:` and `=` you noticed, yes, that's a typo. As for the rest of the answer, this should do the trick, but I don't understand why I can't create keys from other file without this `if` clause - after all, if my files hadn't been divided, I could use this sort of key creation without first checking if the key exists. And why did it work in Python 3.5?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not explaining how to solve the specific error you encounter (other answers already do that), but I'd like
to point out there are more suitable config languages for your use case.  Specifically, [Figura](https://figura.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)
natively supports this sort of overrideability.

Here's an example:

```
# main_config.py
class MainConfig:
    class clients:
        class client1:
            IP = "127.0.0.1"
            User = "admin"

# custom_config.py
class CustomConfig:
    # declare this config is meant to be applied as an override to another
    __override__ = True
    class client2:
        IP = "0.0.0.0"
        User = "root"
```

And combining them in your code:

```
from figura import build_config
full_config = build_config('main_config.MainConfig', 'custom_config.CustomConfig')
```

The flexible [build_config](https://figura.readthedocs.io/en/latest/figura.html#figura.utils.build_config) function treats the first arg as the base config, and the rest as overrides to apply to it.

Full disclosure: I am the author of figura.

Comment: Upvoted for another approach on this issue, but unfortunately I cannot use other modules for this.